# How do I move notes from Microsoft OneNote for Mac to Evernote for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-onenote, evernote

I had been using Evernote. When Microsoft launched OneNote for Mac, I experimented with it for a few months. I'd like to move back to using Evernote, but I'd like to be able to move the notes I created in OneNote (which are almost all text) into Evernote.

Is there a way to manually export notes from OneNote for Mac and import them into Evernote for Mac, or otherwise synchronize notebooks between these products?

If it helps I could also do this from Windows with OneNote 2010 and a current version of Evernote for Windows.

Comment: You do know that OneNote is free on OS X right?

Comment: Just testing this out now.

Comment: From the looks of things I do not think there is an official export option for the mac edition of OneNote. Maybe export them from the windows edition and import them into evernote on windows and they will sync?

Comment: @Ramhound I know, but I also don't see how that's relevant. I'm not switching from OneNote back to Evernote because of cost or lack thereof; I'm switching because I prefer Evernote over OneNote.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get your notes out of OneNote on a Mac other than printing to PDF.

The [Instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/send-notes-in-email-HA102749247.aspx) above for emailing notes from OneNote will not work on a Mac.  Here is a picture from the instructions on how to email notes from within OneNote:
[image]

Here is a screen shot of OneNote on a Mac:
[image]

The OneNote documentation seems to be only relevant to the Windows platforms.  There are other ways that OneNote for the Mac is a crippled version of the original, but it gets a little better with each release.

Comment: The instructions talk about it not working with Win RT, but doesn't mention Mac.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Sure, here is a [picture from the instructions](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/80dfecc2-5606-44e4-80d2-abf2c1dbccd0.png) on how to email notes from within OneNote.  And here is a screen shot of [OneNote on a Mac](http://i.imgur.com/6H1T6JM.png).  See?  No integration with email on MacOS.

Comment: still an issue with version 15.19.1 :(

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet with OneNote is to export them in a file format that works (.pdf) and then import that into Evernote.

Another idea, however, is to email the notes to your [Evernote email address](https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#/article/23480523). They will then appear in evernote.

[Instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/send-notes-in-email-HA102749247.aspx) on how to do both in OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

Fugured it out!

1) subscribe to the upgraded service...even if it's just for a month the $3 is totally worth it. You can cancel after a  month.

2) In OneNote open the note that you want to move to EverNote. Go to File > Share > message.

3) Send it to your EverNote email. Find this in your online EverNote account. At the bottom of the left column click on the "i" and open Settings and then Account Summary. Scroll down to find it under "Email Notes to".

4) copy the address and send yourself a test message. It should populate into your main notebook (mine did take a couple of minutes the first time)

5) the "document kept its original formatting, colors, etc and is editable!! Woohoo!

I DO understand that this process is a bit laborious but you can bang out a bunch pretty fast...AND, as an added bonus I was able to delete a bunch of stuff that I really didn't need to keep, and i initially only moved docs that are active....all depends what your commitment is as to if it is worth it to you. A batch dump would really just make too much sense, right?
It seems that the folks at Microsoft are never really that interested in giving Mac users the same quality and functionality that is available on the PC...this is why I am migrating to EverNote. Cost be damned. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: It is Raystafarian's answer